# Simple modular tensor category and zero entries in its S-matrix

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories, vertex-algebras, modular-tensor-categories

**Question 1**: Is there a simple modular fusion category with a zero entry in its S-matrix?
(or equivalently, with a fusion matrix of zero determinant?)

Yes, by [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446236/34538) below providing the example $\mathrm{PSU}(2)_{7}$. Moreover, the checking paragraph below suggests that $\mathrm{PSU}(2)_{\ell}$ is such an example if and only if $\ell+2$ is odd and composed.

**Question 2**: Is there a simple modular fusion category with a zero entry in each column of its S-matrix, except one?
(or equivalently, with every fusion matrix of zero determinant, except one)

**Checking**
In the pointed case, the fusion matrices are permutation matrices, so of determinant $\pm 1$. The *easiest* non-pointed simple modular fusion categories are $\mathrm{PSU}(2)_{\ell}$, with $\ell$ odd. It is a fusion subcategory of $\mathrm{SU}(2)_{\ell}$, and [BK01, Example 3.3.22] implies that the S-matrix of $\mathrm{SU}(2)_{\ell}$ has no zero entry iff $\ell + 2$ is prime. In particular, the S-matrix of $\mathrm{PSU}(2)_{\ell}$ has no zero entry if $\ell + 2$ is prime. Now by [BK01, Example 3.3.22] again, for all $\ell$, the S-matrix of $\mathrm{SU}(2)_{\ell}$ does not have a zero entry in each column (except one), thus so is for $\mathrm{PSU}(2)_{\ell}$, and we are done. The S-matrix for a modular fusion category of Lie type in general is given by [BK01, Theorem 3.3.20], and examples may be found there. The simple modular fusion category from [Sch22] has also all its fusion matrices of determinant $\pm 1$. A good example to check would be the center of Extended Haagerup [MW17].

**Motivation**
A negative answer to Question 2 can be formulated as follows:
*Statement 1* (Open): Every simple modular fusion category has no zero entry in each column (except one) of its S-matrix.
(or equivalently, has no every fusion matrix of zero determinant, except one).

Observe that Statement 1 and [GNN09, Theorem 6.1] (or, more generally, [Bur23, Theorem 2]) imply:
*Statement 2* (Open): Every simple integral modular fusion category is pointed.

Next, Statement 2 and [LPR23, Theorem 5.8] imply:
*Statement 3* (Open): Every simple integral fusion category is weakly group-theoretical.

*Conclusion*: a negative answer to above question provides a negative answer to [ENO11, Question 2] in the simple case.

---

*References*
[BK01] B. Bakalov, Bojko A. Kirillov, *Lectures on tensor categories and modular functors.*
University Lecture Series, 21. AMS, 2001.
[Bur23] S. Burciu, *On the Galois symmetries for the character table of an integral fusion category.* J. Algebra Appl. 22 (2023), no. 1, Paper No. 2350026.
[ENO11] P. Etingof, D. Nikshych, and V. Ostrik, Weakly group-theoretical and solvable fusion categories, Adv. Math., 226 (2011), pp. 176–205.
[GNN09] S. Gelaki, D. Naidu, D. Nikshych, *Centers of graded fusion categories.* Algebra Number Theory 3 (2009), no. 8, 959--990.
[LPR23] Z. Liu, S. Palcoux, Y. Ren, *Interpolated family of non group-like simple integral fusion rings of Lie type*, Internat. J. Math. (2023), DOI: 10.1142/S0129167X23500301.
[MW17] S. Morrison, K. Walker, *The center of the extended Haagerup subfactor has 22 simple objects.* Internat. J. Math. 28 (2017), no. 1, 1750009.
[Sch22] A. Schopieray, *Non-pseudounitary fusion*. J. Pure Appl. Algebra 226 (2022), no. 5, Paper No. 106927

Comment: For the symmetric case (more precisely, finite group rep) instead of modular, see https://mathoverflow.net/q/401924/34538

Answer (score 3):

I may be misunderstanding the definition of simple (I am using your post [Strongly simple fusion categories: the known examples?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422308/strongly-simple-fusion-categories-the-known-examples) as reference), but I believe that the $(A_1,7)_{1/2}$ quantum group MTC is an example (see Wang et. al's classification paper cited below, formula 5.3.10). The $S$-matrix has a zero entry on its diagonal.

It is simple because the fusion rule for $\alpha^2$ involves $\omega$, the fusion rule for $\omega^2$ involves $\rho$, and the fusion rule for $\rho^2$ involves $\alpha$. Hence, you can't pick a subset of the simple objects and have the fusion be self contained. Hence, $(A_1,7)_{1/2}$ should have no non-trivial fusion subcategories so it should be simple.

*Rowell, Eric; Stong, Richard; Wang, Zhenghan*, [**On classification of modular tensor categories**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1377), Commun. Math. Phys. 292, No. 2, 343-389 (2009). [ZBL1186.18005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1186.18005).

Comment: I made a mistake in my post (I confused l and l+2), now it is fixed. You answer Question 1. Next, Question 2 is about a zero entry in each column except one, so the motivation is intact, and the existence of an example is open to me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an anwser to Question 2 given by Andrew Schopieray by email:

<< Having a zero in your column (or row) is preserved under Galois conjugacy of characters.  All columns having a zero but the unit implies the categorical/Frobenius dimension character is fixed under Galois conjugation, hence such an example must be integral.  So this is equivalent to asking whether there is a simple integral modular tensor category which is not pointed. >>