# Adjoint identity on finite nilpotent groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, characters, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a finite nilpotent group.  Consider the following (adjoint) identity from [BuPa, Theorem 9.6]:

$$\left(\prod_{\chi \in \mathrm{Irr}(G)} \frac{\chi}{\chi(1)} \right)^2 =\frac{|Z(G)|}{|G|}\left(\sum_{\chi \in \mathrm{Irr}(G/Z(G))}\chi(1) \chi \right).$$

**Question**: Did the above identity appear in the literature before [BuPa]?

*Remark*: The name *adjoint* comes from the fact that for any finite group $G$ then the adjoint subcategory $\mathcal{C}_{ad}$ of $\mathcal{C}=\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Rep}(G/Z(G))$, where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$, see [GeNi, Example 3.2].  Note that $\mathrm{Irr}(G/Z(G))$ can be seen as a subset of $\mathrm{Irr}(G)$.

*Remark*: Above identity does not hold on every finite group. There are exactly $144$ finite groups of order less than $32$, and among them, exactly $30$ ones are non-nilpotent, and among
them, the above identity holds only on $\mathrm{SL}(2, 3)$, so it does not hold on the $29$ other ones, e.g. $S_3$ and $D_5$. The above identity does not hold on every finite simple group, for example, it holds on $A_5$ and $A_6$, but not on $A_7$.

*Remark*: In the current version of [BuPa], the square in the LHS of the identity is missing (just a typo).

---

*References*

[BuPa] S. Burciu, S. Palcoux, *Burnside type results for fusion rings*, arXiv:2302.07604 (2023)
[GeNi] S. Gelaki, D. Nikshych, *Nilpotent fusion categories.* Adv. Math. 217 (2008), no. 3, 1053--1071.

Comment: Maybe we should say that the same identity holds for any finite group G whose character table has a zero-entry in any column corresponding to a non-central  conjugacy class.

Comment: Groups with such properties were also discussed in: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401924/the-finite-groups-with-a-zero-entry-in-each-column-of-its-character-table-excep